# About irreducible polynomial over field & characteristic or minimal polynomial of matrix

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, field-theory, linear-transformations, extension-field

Let $F$ be a field and $K$ be a finite extension of $F$, and let $\alpha\in K$.

Consider a linear map $T:K\to K$ is defined by $T(\beta)=\alpha\beta$ for all $\beta\in K$, where $K$ viewed as a finite dimensional vector space over $F$.

Then, using the fact that $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of the representation matrix $A$ of $T$, we obtain the characteristic polynomial $f(x)=\det(A-xI)$ of $A$, where $I$ is the identity matrix with suitable size.

At this point, i have a question.

Q1) Is it true that $f(x)=\text{irr}(\alpha,F)$ or $p(x)=\text{irr}(\alpha,F)$, where $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$?

Q2) What is the relationship between $\text{irr}(\alpha,F)$ and the minimal polynomial of $A$?

I would be very grateful if you could give me some textbooks or brief explanations.

(ps. my algebra level is quite elementary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal polynomial of $T$, hence also of its matrix $A$, *coincides* with the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. 
The key is, if $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n\ \in F[x]$, then we have
 $$f(T)(b)=(a_0\mathrm{id}+a_1T+\dots+a_nT^n)(b)=a_0b+a_1T(b)+a_nT^n(b)=a_0b+a_1\alpha b+\dots +a_n\alpha^nb=f(\alpha)b$$
So, if $\alpha$ is a root of $f$, then $f(T)=0$, and if $f(T)=0$, then in particular $f(T)(1)=0$ which yields $f(\alpha) =0$.